# Print full textarea with CSS only

Tags: html, css

I have textarea blocks on the site I am working on and oftentimes the textareas will contain a lot of text. However, when I print them, they cut off the end of the text.

How can I make sure they fully print? I have tried to increase the height, width and overflow of the textareas by using this, with and without media print, and nothing seems to be increasing their size when I print them.

```
@media print { 
textarea {
    height: 500px; 
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
}
```

They seem to be stuck in whatever size it has defaulted to.

I cannot use JavaScript or PHP for the solution, I can only use CSS.

I am okay with having extra blank space from fixed widths/heights, I just need to have all the content be printed.

Here is a screenshot, you can see the scroll bar is printed as opposed to all the content.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a live preview

Comment: i have attached the screenshot in my original post

Comment: You need to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example so we can help you.

Comment: what would I need to add? this problem can be seen with just attempting to print a normal <textarea>

Comment: Provide that code.